# Make text blink and at the same time change content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a website, and i need to know how to make text blink and change content at the same time, like on this website
http://www.precrafted.com/

I don't know how to be more specific. Thank you for answers.

Comment: To solve problems, [you must create a solvable problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it stands, this question is not a [good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as defined by the basic help center rules.

Comment: A couple of minutes of Googling led me to the [textrotator](https://github.com/peachananr/simple-text-rotator) jQuery plugin that precrafted.com uses.

Comment: take a look at this fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/c9u3megc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this something like this

```
function changeText(){
    $('#idOfYourSpan').hide().val("something new");
    setTimeout(function(){$('#idOfYourSpan').show();},1000);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c9u3megc/

Comment: You can do `show` in the callback for `hide`.

Comment: Maybe hide and than change value?)